# To find out uniq values from an array of hashes based on an input hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array and a hash:

```
a = [
  { :color => "blue", :name => "wind" },
  { :color => "red", :name => "fire" },
  { :color => "white", :name => "wind" },
  { :color => "yellow", :name => "wind" },
  { :color => "green", :name => nil },
  { :color => "black", :name => "snow" }
]

b = { blue: 'blue', white: 'white', red: 'red', green: 'green', black: 'black' }
```

I need to find out unique names based on the input hash to get this:

```
['wind', 'fire', 'snow']
```

I've tried:

```
names = a.map { |i| [i[:color], i[:name]] }
         .delete_if { |key, value| value.nil? }
resultant_names = []

b.values.each do |c|
  if names[c]
    resultant_names << names[c]
  end
end

resultant_names.uniq
```

I need a better approach for this. This one has too many loops.

Comment: Why is the result `['wind', 'fire']`? Why is "snow" **not** part of the desired output?

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing your variables as you are? It feels like this could be a lot simpler were this adjusted. I.E. `b` could be an array, `a` could be a single hash with `colors` as keys and arrays of `names` as values.

Comment: If you see the input hash (b) values, the corresponding names in 'a' would group to the resultant_names (excluding nil values)

Comment: No control over data...

Comment: Ok, so why is 'snow' not in your output?

Comment: Sorry my bad, snow is also part of output. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

While your result does not make sense to me (e.g. it is missing snow) this will work

```
a.map(&:values).reverse.to_h.values_at(*b.values).compact.uniq
#=> ["wind","fire"]
```

To break it down:

```
a.map(&:values).reverse.to_h
#=> {"white"=>"wind", "green"=>nil, "yellow"=>"wind", "red"=>"fire", "blue"=>"wind"}
```

You'll notice snow is missing because when we reverse the list `["white","wind"]` will overwrite `["white","snow"]` when converted to a `Hash`

Then we just collect the values for the given colors from

```
b.values
#=>  ["blue", "white", "red", "green"]
a.map(&:values).reverse.to_h.values_at(*b.values)
#=>  ["wind", "wind", "fire", nil]
```

Then `Array#compact` will remove the `nil` elements and `Array#uniq` will make the list unique.

If snow was intended you could skip the reversal

```
a.map(&:values).to_h.values_at(*b.values).compact.uniq
#=> ["wind", "snow", "fire"]
```

**Either way this is a strange data structure and these answers are only to help with the problem provided as the duplicate colors can cause differing results based on the order in `a`.**

Comment: Sorry my bad, snow is also part of output. Edited the question accordingly

Comment: @VamsiKrishna in that case the second solution will provide the desired output in this specific instance but if `{ :color => "white", :name => "snow" }` is placed before `{ :color => "white", :name => "wind" }` in the original `Array` it will not. Due to the duplication of the color white this answer is very order dependent and may not be suitable for your use case

Comment: This solution seems more readable. But, are the number of loops reduced in this case...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Yes the external loop is limited to `a.map(&:values)` obviously there are internal loops for some of the other method calls but nothing to concern yourself with

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want 'snow' to be in your output array, as there is no other logical explanation. Your code would work if you were to add `.to_h` on the end of line 2, but as you note, it is not very clean or efficient. Also, by converting to a Hash, as a result of duplicate keys, you would potentially lose data.

Here's a tighter construct that avoids the data loss problem:

```
def unique_elements(a, b)
  color_set = b.values.to_set
  a.map { |pair| pair[:name] if color_set.include?(pair[:color]) }.compact.uniq
end
```

First we take the values of `b` and convert them to a set, so that we can efficiently determine if a given element is a member of the set.

Next we map over `a` choosing the names of those members of `a` for which the `[:color]` is included in our color set.

Finally we eliminate `nils` (using `compact`) and choose unique values.

```
>> unique_elements(a, b)
#> ["wind", "fire", "snow"]
```

Comment: the `select` is not really necessary `a.map {|pair| pair[:name] if color_set.include?(pair[:color])}.compact.uniq` would work equally well. and avoids the need for a near full second loop and lookup

Comment: @engineersmnky Agreed. Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by converting `a` to a more useful data structure.

```
h = a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:color]] = g[:name] }
  #=> {"blue"=>"wind", "red"=>"fire", "white"=>"wind", "yellow"=>"wind",
  #    "green"=>nil, "black"=>"snow"}
```

We may then simply write

```
h.values_at(*b.values).compact.uniq
  # => ["wind", "fire", "snow"]
```

This approach has several desireable characteristics:

- the creation of `h` makes the method easier to read
- debugging and testing is made easier by creating `h` as a separate step
- `h` need only be created once even if several values of `b` are to be evaluated (in which case we may wish to make `h` an instance variable).

`h` could be chained to the second statement but I've chosen not to do so for the reasons given above (especially the last one).

Comment: This solution seems more readable. But, are the number of loops reduced in this case...

Comment: well since you have taken it this far and I am going to assume snow is not black (which it wasn't originally hence my answer and caveats) why not go with `a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |g,h| h[g[:color]] << g[:name]}.values_at(*b.values).flatten.compact.uniq`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I edited my answer to address your question (more or less) and also simplified the calculation of `h`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I only chained for brevity in a comment. My actual point was if there are multiple hashes in the beginning array with the same color (as the original question suggested). In this case they would overwrite one another rather than concatenating the natural elements

Comment: @engineersmnky, I see. I merely assumed that, as in the example, the values of `:color` contained no dups.